# Get index in a IQueryable result

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a LINQ query:

```
 var result = (from CC in hc.ClaimCodings
                              join CM in hc.ClaimCodingProcedureCodeModifierXrefs on CC.ClaimCodingID equals CM.ClaimCodingID
                              join PCM in hc.ProcedureCodeModifiers on CM.ProcedureCodeModifierID equals PCM.ProcedureCodeModifierID
                              where CC.CTCustomerSubID == custSub && CC.ClaimID == claimID
                              select new { PCM.ModifierCode });
```

*EDIT*

Which can return 0 to 4 items.  I want to set the value of each Modifier code to a property:

```
     public string ModCode1 { get; set; }

    public string ModCode2 { get; set; }

    public string ModCode3 { get; set; }

    public string ModCode4 { get; set; }

    Modcode1 = result.ModifierCode.getindex(0).firstordefault();

ModeCode2 = second result's ModifierCode;

etc 

etc
```

Unless I'm approaching this completely wrong.  I'm not so good with LINQ yet :(

Comment: “I want to set each item that is returned to a property” ← Could you elaborate on that? Your result in a sequence of strings; how do you want to assign them to a property?

Comment: Sorry I wasnt very clear.  The value being returned from the database should be set to the property.

Comment: @broke: It's *still* not very clear. Aside from anything else, it's not clear why you're using an anonymous type rather than just `select PCM.ModifierCode`.

Comment: Maybe he just wants to rename the property in the anonymous type. In that case, it’s `select new { Modcode1 = PCM.ModifierCode })`.

Comment: Edited question to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: why are you not using a `List<T>` instead of 4 separate properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
var result = 
(
   from CC in hc.ClaimCodings
       join CM in hc.ClaimCodingProcedureCodeModifierXrefs 
           on CC.ClaimCodingID equals CM.ClaimCodingID
       join PCM in hc.ProcedureCodeModifiers 
           on CM.ProcedureCodeModifierID equals PCM.ProcedureCodeModifierID
   where CC.CTCustomerSubID == custSub && CC.ClaimID == claimID && 
         PCM.ModifierCode != null
   select PCM.ModifierCode
).ToList();

ModCode1 = result.Length > 0 ? result[0] : null;
ModCode2 = result.Length > 1 ? result[1] : null;
ModCode3 = result.Length > 2 ? result[2] : null;
ModCode4 = result.Length > 3 ? result[3] : null;
```

Main changes:

- Added `PCM.ModifierCode != null` check within LINQ query.
- Removed redundant anonymous type construction.
- Converted LINQ query result to `List<string>` through `ToList()`.

However, as BrokenGlass said, you’re probably better off storing a list.

Comment: I think this might be what I need.  I'm using property's so that I can bind to 4 text boxes that are inside a list view on an ASP.NET webform.

Comment: In that case, why don’t you use a `Repeater` which constructs a `TextBox` for each item in your list?

Comment: Never used a repeater before... Do you have an example?

Comment: I would suggest reading up a tutorial or two: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can call ToArray() on the results to immediately execute the query and return an array of the values. You can then assign values to the properties using the some ternary operator shorthand which checks the length of the array.

```
res = result.Take(4).ToArray();
Modcode1 = res.Length > 0 ? res[0] : null;
Modcode2 = res.Length > 1 ? res[1] : null;
Modcode3 = res.Length > 2 ? res[2] : null;
Modcode4 = res.Length > 3 ? res[3] : null;
```